# Why would someone use JSON interface for a property

Tags: typescript

While staring at the codebase, I found an interface with definition of the type:

```js
interface Something {
    prop: JSON;
}
```

where `JSON`, upon <kbd>F12</kbd> inspection is the following:

```js
interface JSON {

    /**

     * Converts a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string into an object.

     * @param text A valid JSON string.

     * @param reviver A function that transforms the results. This function is called for each member of the object.

     * If a member contains nested objects, the nested objects are transformed before the parent object is.

     */

    parse(text: string, reviver?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any): any;

    /**

     * Converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.

     * @param value A JavaScript value, usually an object or array, to be converted.

     * @param replacer A function that transforms the results.

     * @param space Adds indentation, white space, and line break characters to the return-value JSON text to make it easier to read.

     */

    stringify(value: any, replacer?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number): string;

    /**

     * Converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.

     * @param value A JavaScript value, usually an object or array, to be converted.

     * @param replacer An array of strings and numbers that acts as a approved list for selecting the object properties that will be stringified.

     * @param space Adds indentation, white space, and line break characters to the return-value JSON text to make it easier to read.

     */

    stringify(value: any, replacer?: (number | string)[] | null, space?: string | number): string;

}



/**

 * An intrinsic object that provides functions to convert JavaScript values to and from the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

 */

declare var JSON: JSON;
```

defined in `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts`

and

```js
interface JSON {

    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;

}
```

defined in `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts`.

[image: VS Code Go to Definition screenshot]

I am aware of the usefulness of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` methods, but is there a legit reason to use this type for any property?

Comment: Could it be that it was a user-created type? How come your code editor has redirected you to two different definitions?

Comment: Hm, not sure, when I do "Go to definition", the list opens up with three items (as would different usages of a property or method show up.

Comment: I added a screenshot as well.

Comment: Do you find anything if you right click on `prop` and then "find all implementations"?

Comment: @gugge: No - just some types that are mocking it in the specs.

Comment: @gugge: I was not clear enough - anywhere in the code it's assigned with `object`s